# How can We correct "Invalid file name: 'con' error" in Android studio?

Tags: android-studio

I have spent time googling but without results. I get following error when creating projects with latest android studio:

```
Invalid file name: 'con'

New Module was only partially completed.
Your project may not compile.
You may want to Undo to get back to the original state
```

[image]

I have also tried previous version of android studio, but without any result.
What could be the cause of this issue and how can I correct it? I am on Windows 10.

Thank you

***I Feel silly now because it was because of con word in package name. The accepted answer helped.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A module name is automatically used as directory name.

As you are on Windows the file-system has several file- and folder-names that are disallowed. `con` is one such disallowed names (case insensitive).

This means no matter what file-system you use as long as you are running Android Studio on Windows you will never ab able to create a file or a folder named `con`.

Other disallowed file names are:

> CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9. <sup>[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)</sup>

Therefore you have two possibilities: Use a different name for the module or use a different OS.

Comment: Hi  thank you for amazing info you gave me here. The problem is I do not do anything myself. This error happens in the moment of creation of project by android studio. What I mean is: I select project type, give this new project name and when android studio starts to generate project files it fails with this error. Why does this happen and how can we correct it? Also project files get generated partially: .java and Androidmanifest.xml files for example are missing.

Comment: @TornikeShavishvili What "project name" do you enter?

Comment: qmpservicepoint but error is same when i live default project name chosen by android studio itself

Comment: @TornikeShavishvili What project type do you select and what `Save Location` is shown (does it contains anything like `con`)? Make sure Save Location points to a valid and empty directory. If that still does not help use Sysinternals Process Monitor to check what files and folders Android Studio is trying to create.

Comment: this is path: "D:\NGTProjects\qmatic\AndroidStudioProjectsGeneral\OrchestraServicePoint" and directory exists. and it is empty. I am running windows virtual machine on my computer. Could this be cause of the issue? (Android studio runs on host os, not in vm)

Comment: @TornikeShavishvili Try a different project type at a different path using a different name and packageName. If the error still occurs use ProcessMonitor to check what files and folders are accessed. The virtual machine shouldn't be a problem for AS itself. May be the Windows ransomware protection that uses virtualization but I don't have experience with that.

Comment: Could this be antivirus issue . . . . or issue with android studio itself? First I will uninstall/reinstall it. Then is issue is same - run on vm.

Comment: I don't think Anti Virus is involved. As I already mentioned use `Sysinternal Process Monitor` (from Microsoft) to monitor disk activity of Android Studio then you will know more.

Comment: @TornikeShavishvili What did you choose for the "Package name" in the New Project wizard? Each of those individual pieces will be made into directories, too. Did you possibly mistype `com`?

Comment: @MikeM. I triple-checked ant mistype-ing is not a case. Even default project name/package name does that. I am a bit frustrated :| I will install android studio on virtual machine and post results here :(

Comment: @Robert unfortunately I never had time to become friends with `Sysinternal Process Monitor` but I will do my best.

Comment: @MikeM. I Checked fourth time and you were right (thanks god!) It was con in package name. Thanks